# Perplexing issue with MultiTrigger and Converter

Tags: xamarin, binding, multitrigger

I have the following converter:

public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            int x = 1;
        }
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and I'm attempting to use it like this, to control IsVisible of a listview based on a code-behind property "CanShowResults", and an activity indicator on the page:

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="White" SeparatorColor="#e0e0e0" IsVisible="False">
            <ListView.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger TargetType="ListView">
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference retrievingActivity}, Path=IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource boolInvert}}" Value="true" />
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Path=CanShowResults}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ListView.Triggers>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

.
.
.
.
.

I'm getting an exception in the Convert method.  I've scoured documentation, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "an exception" is not helpful.  What is the specific exception that is being thrown?

Comment: The throw statement in the converter.  Sorry, I thought that would be clear.  The target type is not a bool, it says.

Comment: what is the actual type being passed?

Comment: System.Object, with no indication of what KIND of object.  It's very strange....

Comment: can you test `if (value is bool)` instead?

Comment: That works -- and I saw during debugging that the value is a bool.  However, every example I've seen of a converter has had this targetType check.  Do you know if that's a quirk of using it with a BindingCondition?

Comment: no idea - I haven't done much hands-on with converters.  You might file an issue in the XF github to see what the devs say.

Comment: OK, thanks for the assist.

Comment: @JeffLandon Hi, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

[targetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter.convert?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_IValueConverter_Convert_System_Object_System_Type_System_Object_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_) is used for pointing out the type to which to convert the value. And there's no need to pass it to your IValueConverter class. It is automatically set depending on what type it wants to convert it to be.

For example, if you consuming the IValueConverter on a Lable's Text the `targetType` is `System.String`. Your `targetType` is always `System.Object` because you utilized it on a `BindingCondition`.

If you want to point out the type manually, you could try `ConverterParameter`:

```
<BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference retrievingActivity}, Path=IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource boolInvert}, ConverterParameter={x:Type x:Boolean}}" Value="true" />
```

Then retrieve it in `IValueConverter` class like:

```
try
{
    if ((Type)parameter != typeof(bool))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int x = 1;
}
return !(bool)value;
```

Moreover, we used the `if (value is bool)` directly as what Jason said.